# MediaPlayer сохранить буферизованный файл

Tags: android, mediaplayer

Я использую `MediaPlayer` для воспроизведения аудиофайла, который находится в сети internet. Все отлично воспроизводится, но теперь мне нужно параллельно сохранить воспроизводимый файл.
Я конечно могу его повторно скачать и сохранить, но ведь он уже загружен в `MediaPlayer`. Как мне достать его оттуда и сохранить?
Еще вариант - как подсунуть `Mediaplayer'у` поток байтов для воспроизведения, например

Comment: Не уверен, что оно, но вдруг: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17924922/3212712

Comment: Вот ещё что-то: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18627606/3212712

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, похоже на правду. Смогу проверить только через пару часов

Comment: Главное отпишитесь - интересно мне это тоже)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, нашел хорошее решение, и описал в ответе

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В итоге решил изменить подход: Вместо того, чтобы выковыривать кешированный файл из `MediaPlayer`, я решил кешировать его вручную. Для этого я использую прокси-сервер, который работает внутри самого приложения, и кеширует все файлы, проходящие через него.
Конкретно использую эту библиотеку [AndroidVideoCache](https://github.com/danikula/AndroidVideoCache)
Несмотря на название, она подходит так же и для кеширования аудио-файлов. Работает следующим образом:

```
proxy = new HttpProxyCacheServer.Builder(this).build();
...
String proxyUrl = proxy.getProxyUrl(file.getURL());
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, Uri.parse(proxyUrl));
```